# Inderscience Latex template lower margin problem

Tags: line-spacing

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{singlecol-new}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\RequirePackage[2014/01/01]{latexrelease}
\usepackage{natbib,stfloats}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}


\def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}

\theoremstyle{TH}{
    \newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
    \newtheorem{theorem}[lemma]{Theorem}
    \newtheorem{corrolary}[lemma]{Corrolary}
    \newtheorem{conjecture}[lemma]{Conjecture}
    \newtheorem{proposition}[lemma]{Proposition}
    \newtheorem{claim}[lemma]{Claim}
    \newtheorem{stheorem}[lemma]{Wrong Theorem}
    \newtheorem{algorithm}{Algorithm}
}

\theoremstyle{THrm}{
    \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
    \newtheorem{question}{Question}[section]
    \newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
    \newtheorem{scheme}{Scheme}
}

\theoremstyle{THhit}{
    \newtheorem{case}{Case}[section]
}

\makeatletter
\def\theequation{\arabic{equation}}

\JOURNALNAME{\TEN{\it International Journal of Communication Networks and Distributed Systems}}
%Vol. \theVOL, No. \theISSUE, \thePUBYEAR\hfill\thepage}}%
%


\def\BottomCatch{%
\vskip 30pt
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\begin{table}[b]%
\NINE\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lcr@{}}
\\[-10pt]
Copyright \copyright\ 2012 Inderscience Enterprises Ltd. & &%
\end{tabular*}%

\vskip 40pt%
\vskip 60pt%
\end{table}%
}
\makeatother
```

[image]

**The text overlaps with lower and right margins!!**

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) please post a full minimal example that others can copy and test as is. Might also be an idea to specify where people can download that document class (never seen it before)

Comment: I know it isn't an answer, but I would like to offer the following suggestion to the enquirer on behalf of Inderscience so that we can help: "Please send your tex (source) and PDF files to our typesetters at inderscience@galaxyeservices.com, so that they can troubleshoot the problem and send you a working/revised template." Is there any way to do that, e.g. add it as a comment as opposed to an answer? Many thanks,
Darren Simpson
Information Administrator
Inderscience Publishers